# jQuery add a class only if it does not have another class

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation animation that is being applied to elements with the "js" class - via a css background. I don't want this animation to occur on the link for the current page (a class "current" is being echo'd out by PHP to the current page).

So basically the page your on (current page) link in the main nav will have a class of current, the others a class of js - and get the animation. How do apply that logic in a funciton? I can do it via css background but want to do it in js.
Here is working js used in combination with css for desired look:

```
 $(function() {
    $("ul#mainNav li a").addClass("js");
        $("ul#mainNav li a").hover(
          function () {
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 200);
            $(this).animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -5px)"}, 150);
          },
          function () {
            $(this).animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -130px)"}, 200);

          }
        );
    });
```

What I'm trying to no avail:

```
$(function() {
    if($("ul#mainNav li a").hasClass("current")) {
    //do nothing
    } else {
    $(this).addClass("js")
    }

//rest of animation function
```

});

```
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this.  If you need the selector you have for other things, you can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainNav li a").each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
            $(this).addClass("js")
        }
    });

//rest of animation function
});
```

If you don't need that whole selector for other things, then you can do it more simply like this:

```
$("#mainNav li a").not(".current").addClass("js");
```

Note, I've removed the ul from the start of your main selector as it is not required since ids are unique.

Comment: jfriend00 & Chris G. is there a reason to use "!" for not over the ":not" selector? both seem to work for me...

Comment: `.not()` is a function call.  `!` is built into the language.  Use `!` if appropriate for speed and size.  Some situations require one or the other depending upon the actual code.

Comment: It can help to add context (like `ul`) to your selector. It makes it readable for yourself, and it allows you to specify specific elements in case you reuse id's over pages. In this case, you got an li too, which (almost) implies the ul, though.

Comment: In 99% of the cases, it just slows down the selector engine and doesn't add any functionality.  In the other 1% of the cases, if you're overloading the same id name on different pages on different tag types and trying to use the tag type to target different script to different pages, then you kind of get what you have coming to you as that's just a brittle way to do it.  Much better to use a master class name at a higher level to distinguish different types of pages or just use separate IDs for separate purposes.  I get your readability notion, but I don't think that's worth overspecifying.

Comment: went with the "!" solution over the ":not" - thx for the explanation @jfriend00

Answer (score 5):

```
$("ul#mainNav li a").not(".current").addClass("js");
```

Your `if` should work too, but you mix up `this` and `$("ul#mainNav li a")`.

Comment: I figured this out, slightly different then yours "$("ul#mainNav li a:not(.current)").addClass("js");" anything wrong with that?

Comment: Nope. Fine too. I don't like those selectors to be too long, especially with the 'not' in it. So I would choose mine for readability, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: is the li in the selector needed here? Or, if mainNav is the id how about $("#mainNav a:not(.current).addClass("js");

Comment: No, you don't select #mainNav, you select links (anchors/a) within list items (li) within that element.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(! $("ul#mainNav li a").hasClass("current")) {
    $("ul#mainNav li a").addClass("js")
}
```

The other answer is better, but this is how your if statement would work if you insisted to do it that way. $(this) only works in the correct scope. You're confusing its usage for when you are using a closure like:

$('a').each(function(){
       $(this).stuff();
   });

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector provided by jQuery to do it more succinctly:

```
$("ul#mainNav li a:not(.current)").addClass("js")
```

Comment: exactly what I did, is there a reason to not use ":not" in favor of "!"

Comment: @jfriend00 seemed to already answer this for you in his accepted answer, but just for posterity sake, the `!` wouldn't work in the selector scheme, and vise-versa.  It's just a matter of context.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this to us on a live event (such as .live('click', )

```
 $("ul#mainNav li a").not(".current").addClass("js");
```

GolezTrol's   '.not' answer (above) although effective usually can fall down on live events.

So I would suggest using the answer supplied by Chris G. (below)

```
 if(! $("ul#mainNav li a").hasClass("current")) {
  $("ul#mainNav li a").addClass("js")
 }
```

I hope this is useful to someone as it may save them some time trying to figure out what they have done wrong (as it was in my case)